# Modular Web Components with View-Based Data-Binding context

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

I'm trying to make my code as modular as possible and mimic the patterns of WPF and Caliburn.Micro. Here's what I've tried so far using Knockout components.

**Component ViewModel**

```
function welcomeViewModel() {
   this.greeting = 'Hello world!;
}
```

**App ViewModel**

```
function appViewModel() {
   this.firstGreetingVM = new welcomeViewModel();
   this.secondGreetingVM = new welcomeViewModel();
}
```

**App View**

```
<WelcomeWidget data-bind-to="firstGreetingVM"/>
<WelcomeWidget data-bind-to="secondGreetingVM"/>
```

How can I define the context (what view-model to use) *in the view itself?*

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any view model you want for a component if you register it appropriately. This approach will let you either pass your component a `viewModel` in the params or have it create a new view model using your params.

```
ko.components.register('WelcomeWidget', {
    template: ...
    viewModel: function (params = {}) {
        return params.viewModel || new WelcomeWidgetViewModel(params);
    },
});
```

**AppViewModel**

```
function AppViewModel() {
   this.firstGreetingVM = new WelcomeWidgetViewModel({greeting: 'first greeting'});
   this.secondGreetingVM = new WelcomeWidgetViewModel({greeting: 'second greeting', someOtherProperty: 'howdy'});
}
```

**AppViewModel.html**

```
<WelcomeWidget params="viewModel: firstGreetingVM"></WelcomeWidget>
<WelcomeWidget params="viewModel: secondGreetingVM"></WelcomeWidget>
<WelcomeWidget params="greeting: 'third greeting', someOtherProperty: 'blah'"></WelcomeWidget>
```

**WelcomeWidgetViewModel**

```
function WelcomeWidgetViewModel(options = {}) {
   this.greeting = options.greeting;
   this.someOtherProperty = options.someOtherProperty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, hadn't realised you could do that. Next problem is informing the viewmodel it is now attached to a view. :D

Comment: I follow a pattern inspired by many MVVM frameworks. Every view model _can_ implement an `onPresented` function that I call on it when appropriate. *When* something is presented in a web app is very dependent on the context. It is usually the responsibility of the parent component to call `onPresented` on its child components.

Comment: Found this snippet. http://jsfiddle.net/gLcfxkv6/1/ . The second issue was getting Snap to draw when the view was attached. so I think I could use this snippet for that.

Comment: ... dam, that requires the template create the viewmodel. :(

Comment: That approach is how you can (asynchronously) get the view model of a component that creates its own view model. If you pass in the view model, you could simply call a method on it in the viewModel function in `ko.components.register`.